# Prevent top app bar compress effect while scrolling within a Lazy lists without first item visible

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have a top bar which disappears while scrolling down and shows up while moving up within a lazy column. It is an example from [android developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#TopAppBar(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets,androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarColors,androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarScrollBehavior))

I was playing with the sample for a while and I added a box over the list.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Preview
@Composable
fun TopAppBarSample() {
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()
    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text(
                        "TopAppBar",
                        maxLines = 1,
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                    )
                },
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { /* doSomething() */ }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Menu,
                            contentDescription = "Localized description"
                        )
                    }
                },
                actions = {
                    // RowScope here, so these icons will be placed horizontally
                    IconButton(onClick = { /* doSomething() */ }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Favorite,
                            contentDescription = "Localized description"
                        )
                    }
                    IconButton(onClick = { /* doSomething() */ }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Favorite,
                            contentDescription = "Localized description"
                        )
                    }
                },
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
            )
        },
        content = { innerPadding ->
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues = innerPadding)) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(200.dp)
                        .background(Color.Gray)
                ) {

                }

                LazyColumn(
                    contentPadding = innerPadding,
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
                ) {
                    val list = (0..75).map { it.toString() }
                    items(count = list.size) {
                        Text(
                            text = list[it],
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

While it works, I want to make it such that if I am scrolling back up within the list, the app bar would only display back if the first item is visible again on the list instead of while scrolling back up at any point.

This is what I am trying to avoid unless '0' is visible. Can someone guide me through?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be what you're looking for!

```
scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.exitUntilCollapsedScrollBehavior()
```

Comment: I would have done that if I wanted the app bar pinned.

I am okay with how it works in the sample above but I don't want the app bar to show if I have not scroll back to the first item in the lazy list.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question, I am not aware of a solution for this as of now.

Comment: I was reading through the documentation and came across [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/TopAppBarDefaults#exitUntilCollapsedScrollBehavior(androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarState,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.animation.core.AnimationSpec,androidx.compose.animation.core.DecayAnimationSpec)), is it what you're looking for by chance?

Comment: It is exactly what I was looking for and works like a charm. Thank you.

Can you edit your answer above let me mark it as useful?

Comment: Hello again, sorry for the delay, I edited the answer. Thank you as well! :)